# full screen divs with margin

Tags: css, layout

I have a slideshow built using the jbgallery script that I am trying to incorporate into a page on my site. The images in the slideshow have a width and height of 100%. I have a navigation bar at the bottom of the page with a height of 90 pixels.

My code is:

```
<style type="text/css">

body{ height:100%;
  background-color:#444;
   margin: 0;}

 div.fullscreenslideshow{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding-bottom:90px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="fullscreenslideshow">
<iframe src="slideshow.html" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%">Your browser doesn't support iFrames.</iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

While this looked to have the desired effect it is producing a scroll bar on the page (as the 90 pixel padding is stretching the page beyond the 100% height it has been set to).

Basically, how to I adjust the css to ensure I get the slideshow in the page with a 90 pixel space beneath it, and without cropping the image (by setting the height to 90% for example on the fullscreenslideshow div css) or producing an overflow?

Been playing around with this for hours now and think I have hit the wall hence the request for help! Out of interest, when I adjusted the padding-bottom to margin-bottom there was no effect on the page.

Thanks for any help in advance,

JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add a negative margin to the bottom of the container that needs to shrink, so there's no need for javascript?

```
margin-top: -90px;
```

**edit**: I got something

First, add this to your div.fullscreenslideshow

```
margin-top: -90px
```

Now, go the page slideshow.html and add this:

```
margin-top: 90px
```

To:

- div.jbg-loading
- .jbgallery .jbg-wrap
- .jbgs-wrapper (you will have to add this one to the css yourself, it doesn't exist yet

I got it to work on my computer (compared it to the other link, and it shows exactly the same).

Comment: +1 works great! tested IE7,IE8, O, Moz, Chrome, Safari : http://jsbin.com/ufayah/edit#javascript,html,live. Than just a bit of JS/jQ to resize on win-resize (with animation) the inner container and ... voilá!

Comment: it does work, however it is cropping the top of the images by this 90px margin. I am trying to incorporate the entire image (which slideshow.html displays as 100% width and 100% height) without any such cropping, hence the desperate attempt to get help here!
I think given this, the jquery option is probably the best methodology if only I could get it working....thanks for your help though. JD

Comment: I feel like keeping this stuff in css is the proper way to work. There has to be a way to do this with css. There's no chance you have a link?

Comment: completely agreed and going insane trying to get this working!! I have uploaded the jquery version to www.biid.co/layout.html and the jsbin version above to www.biid.co/layout1.html.

like I mentioned earlier, I am trying to achieve something similar to http://www.taylorhowes.com/#/home without using flash.

Appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks again, JD

Comment: I've got it to work (but didn't check cross-browser, tough it should work on other browser to). See edit...

Comment: thanks for all your work on this - unfortunately it is now cropping the bottom of the images by 90px unless I have entered something wrong somewhere? Will keep trying it out - do you have an example of your testing you could possibly upload so I can see it? Thanks again, JD

Comment: well, I got it to to the same as your javascript example, which is apparently doing the same cropping. I think it might have to do with the slideshow you're using, I think that one expects that it will always run on the full page. I think it's gonna be really hard to achieve with css. Is there somewhere in you can set the height from the slideshow?

Comment: the slideshow css is part of the jbgallery framework, specifically at http://www.biid.co/jbgallery-3.0.css. Got a horrible feeling this just simply wont be possible at all given all your kind input and my rapidly declining patience and optimism!

Answer (score 1):

Since your div is already `position:absolute;` you can simply set `bottom:90px` to cause the div to simulate a `margin-bottom`:

```
div.fullscreenslideshow{
    bottom:90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JQuery you can use this code:

```
$("div.fullscreenslideshow").css(height: (parseInt($(window).height()) - 90));
```

run this after load your page complete. And have good time.

Comment: with margin or css you haven't this height fix.

Comment: Ok have added: 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){ $("div.fullscreenslideshow").css('height', (parseInt($(window).height()) - 90); }); 
</script>
but still getting a syntax error!? Thanks again for your help. JD

Comment: if you try like that site, Its full flash, but you can set your website body min-height and min-width and try this with percent or pixel, but the best way is that you set width and height after load page and then assign them, create function to re size your elements.

Comment: I'm so sorry replace this part `$("div.fullscreenslideshow").css(height: (parseInt($(window).height()) - 90));` :D

Comment: thanks for that - have uploaded a test version to www.biid.co/layout.html but still seem to be having the same issue despite including this javascript. Very frustrating....! Any other ideas much appreciated.Thanks, JD